# Disabling Anti-Aliasing for fonts

Tags: iphone, pixel, antialiasing

I'm writing a retro type game for the iPhone, and need to render a pixel style font to the screen. However, it looks nice and sharp when I run it in the simulator, but not when I run it on the device. Is there any way that I can disable Anti-Aliasing for fonts? I have already tried this:

```
CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetShouldSmoothFonts(c, FALSE);
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(c, FALSE);
CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(c, FALSE);
```

Also, I'm using the font rendering class from http://github.com/zynga/FontLabel/tree/master

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out, when I was rotating my UIView to draw in landscape mode, I wasn't using enough digits for PI (3.14159 vs 3.14159265), and that fixed it. ^^

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the views and / or layers in the hierarchy leading down to where your text is being drawn are aligned to integral pixel boundaries ( (10.0, 20.0), etc.).  This can cause blurring of the drawn text.

Additionally, looking at the code for FontLabel, I don't think it takes into account the fact that Quartz drawing is aligned to half-pixel coordinates (you need to draw at (10.5, 20.5) to get sharp features, for example).  I'm not quite sure where to correct this, but you could try shifting the `point` in `-drawTextInRect:` by a half pixel in X and Y and see if that clears up the font drawing.